# Rock Paper Scissors function not returning an appropriate result

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an exercise and I'm having some issues with the code. I spend some time figuring out the rock paper scissors formula using differentials instead of typing each scenario with an if. But I'm having some issues trying to make it work in www.repl.it

```
var rock = 0
var paper = 1
var scissors = 2
var computerMove = rock;
var playerMove = paper;

function getWinner(playerMove,computerMove) {
  var winner;

  if (computerMove == playerMove){
     console.log("draw")
  }
  else if ((playerMove - computerMove + 3) % 3 == 1){
     var winner = "player"
  }
  else {
     winner = "computer"
  }
  return winner;
}
```

I've never used functions before, I know the formula is right to determine the winner, but I can't get anything assigned to the variable "winner". I don't get any errors here but winner seems to contain nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Works for me. Where are you calling the function? i.e.

Answer=getWinner('rock', 'paper');

Comment: How are you determining that `winner` contains nothing? Also, I suggest setting a default value for `winner`. IE `var winner = "defaultVal"`

Comment: Is the issue that your logic never finds a match? I'm not sure what the question is here.

Comment: in repl.it.. If I enter the code, nothing comes up to the right. If I try to call up the variable "winner" it gives me the following error: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: winner"

Comment: If I add   else if ((playerMove - computerMove + 3) % 3 == 1){
     var winner = "player"
     console.log("you won")
  } nothing gets printed on the screen!

Comment: You should not be redeclaring `winner` (which you do by putting `var` before it) in the second `if else`. This creates a variable local to that scope, and the variable you want to assign to is never being assigned.

Comment: @socialight http://repl.it/baC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments in the code for explanations:

```
var rock = 0
var paper = 1
var scissors = 2
var computerMove = rock;
var playerMove = paper;

//declare variable outside the function if you want to be able to access it from outside of the function (look into variable scope)
var winner;

function getWinner(playerMove,computerMove) {
    if (computerMove == playerMove){
        // set a value in case of draw
        winner = "draw"
    }
    else if ((playerMove - computerMove + 3) % 3 == 1){
        // don't redeclare the variable!
        winner = "player"
    }
    else {
        winner = "computer"
    }
    return winner;
}

//call the function so it actually executes
getWinner(playerMove,computerMove);

//this should print out your answer now
console.log(winner);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if that's your entire code, you're missing the actual *call* of the function.

The goal of functions is to write reusable procedures, which you can call multiple times.

```
var rock = 0
var paper = 1
var scissors = 2
var computerMove = rock;
var playerMove = paper;

function getWinner(playerMove,computerMove) {
  var winner;

  if (computerMove == playerMove){
     console.log("draw")
  }
  else if ((playerMove - computerMove + 3) % 3 == 1){
     var winner = "player"
  }
  else {
     winner = "computer"
  }
  return winner;
}


var winner = getWinner(playerMove, computerMove);
console.log( winner );
```

Also, you're missing the tie condition.

You could start the internal `winner` var in the "tie" state, and overwrite the "tie" if you meet a condition.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to keep studying functions. From your code above, you've never actually called the function. You should also format your code a bit better so it's more readable. This should work:

```
var rock = 0;
var paper = 1;
var scissors = 2;

var computerMove = rock;
var playerMove = paper;

var winner;

function getWinner(playerMove, computerMove) {
    if (computerMove == playerMove) {
       winner = "draw";
    } else if ((playerMove - computerMove + 3) % 3 == 1) {
        winner = "player";
    } else {
        winner = "computer";
    }
    return winner;
}

console.log(getWinner(playerMove, computerMove));
```

Answer (score 0):

You were overriding winner in one of the conditions, plus I didn't see where you were calling the getWinner function.

```
var rock = 0
var paper = 1
var scissors = 2
var computerMove = rock;
var playerMove = paper;

function getWinner(playerMove,computerMove) {
  var winner;

  if (computerMove == playerMove) 
  {
    console.log("draw");
  }
  else if ((playerMove - computerMove + 3) % 3 == 1)
  { 
    winner = "player";
  }
  else 
  {
    winner = "computer";
  }

  return winner;
}

$(function(){
  $('#txtWinner').text(getWinner(playerMove, computerMove));
});
```

Check out this plunker with a working code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EEWbdjsp0aHR87Tx2OER?p=preview